# Applet not loaded in IE 64 bit in Windows 7 64 bit machine

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet

The applet is not loading with JRE 64-bit for IE10 and IE11(64-bit).

This is because when we open IE in 64-bit machine, it creates two IE processes one is for 32-bit and the other one is for 64-bit. Due to which the JRE is not able to identify the proper IE version to be used.

We need to find the solution without editing in registry editor.

Please help on this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: **it creates two IE processes one is for 32-bit and the other one is for 64-bit.** is not the reason the applet is not working. You need to provide more information.

Comment: Hi thanks for ur reply. In my application,Applet is not loaded in IE 64 bit/windows 64 bit.I tried with registry editor,setting TabProcGrowth in registry editor which is solved. But I dont want this method to implement in client machines.So i need some other solution.

Comment: Then look in the Java console for any errors. See [How do I enable and view the Java Console?](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml).

Comment: If you tell us **what** error was fixed by using TabProcGrowth (set to some value you haven't mentioned) we might be able to help. Please edit the original question with **all** the required information otherwise we cannot help.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I cannot up my application using JRE/IE 64 /Windows 7 bit.Because applet was not loaded in IE 64 bit(while running IE 64 bit- its showing  IE processes one is for 32-bit and the other one is for 64-bit in task manager).So tried to find the solution in google, i got the solution(i.e setting TabProcGrowth is 0 then its solved.).But I want alternative soltion.